# Retornar valores em formato de hora

Tags: golang

Possuo uma `struct` com 2 `ints` e preciso retornar estes valores em `string` porém em formato de hora.

```
type Clock struct {
    hour   int
    minute int
}

func New(hour, minute int) Clock {
    return Clock{hour, minute}
}

func (c Clock) String() string {
    return strconv.Itoa(c.hour) + ":" + strconv.Itoa(c.minute)
}
```

O retorno da função `String()` não inclui os devidor "zeros" aos numeros pois eles são do tipo `inteiro`.

```
retornado: "8:0", desejado "08:00"
retornado "10:3", desejado "10:03"
```

Este desafio prõpoe que não se use o `date` que já vem embutido justo ao `Go`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma muito simples seria adicionar 0 a esquerda até que haja dois números, você tem o `fmt.Sprintf` que pode fazer isso. Se for utilizar ficaria como:

```
func (c Clock) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%02v:%02v", strconv.Itoa(c.hour), strconv.Itoa(c.minute))
}
```

Mas, você neste caso não precisa do `strconv`, poderia utilizar:

```
func (c Clock) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%02d:%02d", c.hour, c.minute)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/nQi80Yj_vh

Existem várias opções, inclusive um `for` como esse extremamente simplório:

```
func lpad(s, value string, length int) string {

    for len(s) < length {
        s = value + s
    }

    return s
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/02gfYXqxRx

---

*O Golang tem o [`Time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/) que pode ser utilizado para questões de tempo, adição de datas, horas e também permite converter para string...*

Comment: obrigado, mas o desafio diz que não posso utilizar o package `time`, estou quebrando a cabeça para criar a função `Add()` para segundos!